# How to get the data values and data type from flatbuffer at runtime

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I have an a flatbuffer schema defined like this

```
enum Payload : uint8 { BLOB, STRPARAM } //type of payload

table Header
{
    payload: Payload;
    sender: string;
    module: string;
    command: string;
    parameter: string;
    timestamp: string; 
    status: string; // used for reply from Daemon: success or fail
    message: string; // Status message, to get more info when request fails
}

table BlobPacket
{
    value: [byte];
}

table StrParamPacket
{
    value1: string; // e.g. "4"
    value2: string; // e.g. "5.7"
}

union PacketData 
{
    BlobPacket, StrParamPacket
}

table DaemonRequest
{   
    header:Header; //Tells information about the packet
    data:PacketData; //Actual data
}

root_type DaemonRequest;
```

Which is packed as a request using following code

```
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder* _builder = nullptr;

    DaemonRequestT request;
    HeaderT header;
    BlobPacketT blobPacket;
    StrParamPacketT strParamPacket;

    header.payload = 0;//str param
    header.sender = sender;
    header.module = module;
    header.command = command;
    header.parameter = parameter;

    auto headerOffset = CreateHeader(*_builder, &header);

    strParamPacket.value1 = value1;
    strParamPacket.value2 = value2;

    auto strParamPacketOffset = CreateStrParamPacket(*_builder, &strParamPacket);

    auto req = CreateDaemonRequest(*_builder, &header, PacketData::StrParamPacket, strParamPacketOffset.Union());
```

This  request is then sent to the server,which unpacks the request
using

```
auto req= UnPackDaemonRequest(receivedBuffer);
```

With this request I can get header details using commands like `req->header->command` .
However I am having problem getting the data_type and data of the tables in union.

I tried following the flatbuffer tutorial ,but there is not much documentation how to get the data after unpacking .
The generated file -> "https://pastebin.com/zLEyd8BE" (Uses --gen-object-api  --scoped-enums --cpp)

I tried getting the data using this

```
    auto union_type = req.data_type(); //error
    if (union_type == PacketData::StrParamPacket) 
    {
        auto strParamPacket = static_cast<const StrParamPacket*>(req->data());//error
        auto command = req->header->command; //std::sting
        auto parameter = req->header->parameter; //std::string
        auto message = req.get()->header->message; //std::string&
        auto value1 = strParamPacket.get()->value1; //std::string&
        auto value2 = strParamPacket.get()->value2; //std::string&
    }
```

This results in the following error

```
: error: ‘class std::unique_ptr<DaemonRequestT>’ has no member named ‘data_type’; did you mean ‘deleter_type’?
     auto union_type = req.data_type(); //error
                           ^~~~~~~~~
                           deleter_type
../Daemon/Daemon.cpp:155:76: error: no match for call to ‘(PacketDataUnion) ()’
         auto strParamPacket = static_cast<const StrParamPacket*>(req->data());//error
```

Answer (score 0):

(deleted previous answer now that question has been clarified).

FlatBuffers has 2 APIs: the default, efficient, the way FlatBuffers was meant to be used API, and an optional "Object API" that you should only be using if you special needs.

You are using the Object API mostly, though you are trying to access the union as if it was the base API. As you can see from the error, `req` is of type `std::unique_ptr<DaemonRequestT>` (not `DaemonRequest`) which has a `data` member of type `PacketDataUnion`, which in turn have covenience methods like `AsStrParamPacket` which does the cast for you (or return nullptr if wrong type).

Comment: 1) Updated the question ,please have a look
2) About the payload enum,Thanks, will change that

Comment: Changed answer to reflect your new question.